# Distance between point and line segments

Tags: graphics, geometry

How would you determine the shortest distance between a point and one or more segments?

For example, what is the shortest distance between the point and the two segments below? Clearly the point is closer to the right line segment. That means the shortest distance between the point and the line segments is equal to the distance between the point and the right segment.

[image: Example: point and two lines]

```
point = {{8, 15}}
lines = {{{20, 10}, {11, 27}}, {{11, 27}, {1, 27}}}
Show[Graphics[{Thick, Line@lines}], 
Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Pink, Point@point}]]
```

Can you think of a way that also works with an arbitrary number of segments?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html

Comment: @YvesKlett Your link refers to the theory shortest distance. I would like to know how you can calculate distance in practice (with Mathematica of course).

Comment: When you say "arbitrary number of lines", do you mean line, line segment, or ray?

Comment: @Silvia I mean the union of the line segments

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In version 10 (now available publicly through the Programming Cloud), use [`RegionNearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionNearest.html)

```
point = {8, 15};
line = Line[{{{20, 10}, {11, 27}}, {{11, 27}, {1, 27}}}];

np = RegionNearest[line, point]
(* {5663/370, 6981/370} *)

Graphics[{PointSize[Large], {line, Point[point]}, {Red, Point[np]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: OR since the damn Programming cloud has not worked (Server error) since it was released, just use the same `RegionNearest` in v9 as I did [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48565/faster-way-to-compute-the-distance-from-a-point-to-a-surface-in-3d/48567#48567)

Answer (score 16):

Using the parametric equation of the lines.

```
point = {8, 15}
lines = {{{20, 10}, {11, 27}}, {{11, 27}, {1, 27}}}

distance[{start_, end_}, pt_]:= Module[{param = ((pt - start).(end - start))/Norm[end - start]^2},
                               EuclideanDistance[pt, start + Clip[param , {0, 1}] (end - start)]];

Min[distance[#, point] & /@ lines]

(*159/Sqrt[370]*)
```

Plotting isodistance lines

```
l  = Table[{Cos[2 Pi n/5], Sin[2 Pi n/5]}, {n, 1, 6}];
l1 = Partition[Riffle[l, l[[2 ;;]]], 2];
Quiet@ContourPlot[Min[distance[#, {x, y}] & /@ l1], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 12):

Not as elegant as belisarius' first answer but was a bit faster; now slower than the new one.  A bit of explanation:  If the point on the line segment $PQ$ closest to $X$ is on $PQ$, then the exterior (supplementary) angles of the triangle $PXQ$ at $P$ and $Q$ will be greater than a right angle and the cosines will be negative.  [*Edit*: To clarify, `cosAngles` is actually a list of `Dot` products, which are just positive numbers times the cosines; and we only use the sign.]

```
lines = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {10, 2, 2}];
point = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {2}];

cosAngles = Dot @@@ Partition[Differences[{#1, #2, #3, #1}], 2, 1] &; 
nearest[{P_, Q_}, X_] := Module[{points},
  If[And @@ Negative[cosAngles[X, P, Q]],
   P + Projection[X - P, Q - P], First@Nearest[{P, Q}, X]]
  ];
findNearest[lines_, point_] := 
  Nearest[nearest[#, point] & /@ lines, point];
distance[lines_, point_] := 
  Norm[First@findNearest[lines, point] - point];
```

Here's the output:

```
point
findNearest[lines, point]
distance[lines, point]
```

> ```
> {7.48559, 3.5353}
>
> {{8.20107, 4.23693}}
>
> 1.0021
> ```

Here's a picture of what's going on:

```
g := Module[{distPts, nearPt},
  distPts = nearest[#, point] & /@ lines;
  nearPt = First@Nearest[distPts, point];
  Graphics[{Line@lines, Blue, Thin, Line[{point, #} & /@ distPts], 
    Point[nearest[#, point] & /@ lines], Thick, Line[{point, nearPt}],
     Red, Point@point}]
  ]

g
```

> [image: Nearest points on line segments]

Same lines, different point.  The nearest point is an end point of a segment.

```
Block[{point = {8, 9}},
 Print[distance[lines, point]];
 g
 ]
```

> ```
> 1.46937
> ```
>
> [image: Nearest points on line segments II]

Comment: I think my new solution is faster :)

Comment: @belisarius Touché!  Nice work.  About twice as fast, or a little better, on a 1000 lines.

Comment: Actually 60% faster (1.3/0.8). I really liked the other approach (it seemed more "elegant"), but it was really slow

Comment: @belisarius Well I can't find a different idea that's faster.  As a math teacher, I admire your geometric `distance` function more than using `MinValue`.  It's faster still if you skip `Module` and insert the `param` formula directly.

Answer (score 8):

The numbers shown are the normal distances. 8.266 is the smaller distance. ref above for the equation of the normals.

```
x0 = 8; y0 = 15;
point = {{x0, y0}};
(*x1=8;y1=20; x2=10;y2=22; x3=12;y3=28*)
x1 = 20; y1 = 10; x2 = 11; y2 = 27; x3 = 1; y3 = 27;
lines = {{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}, {{x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}};
v1 = {y2 - y1, -(x2 - x1)};
r1 = {x1 - x0, y1 - y0};
v2 = {y3 - y2, -(x3 - x2)};
r2 = {x3 - x0, y3 - y0};

d1 = Abs@Dot[v1, r1]/Norm[v1];
d2 = Abs@Dot[v2, r2]/Norm[v2];

Labeled[
 Graphics[{
   {Thick, Line@lines}, {PointSize[Large], Pink, Point@point}
   }, Axes -> True, GridLines -> {Range[5, 20, 1], Range[10, 30, 1]}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> LightGray],
 Grid[{{"distance to first line ", N@d1}, 
   {"distance to second line ", N@d2}}, Alignment -> Left]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This works for the line segments given by the OP, but doesn't seem to work in some other case, such as when the line segments are changed to x1 = 8; y1 = 20; x2 = 10; y2 = 22; x3 = 12; y3 = 28;

Answer (score 4):

This solution I am about to present is effectively a blend of Michael's and belisarius's approaches. To wit,

```
PointLineDistance[pt_, {s1_, s2_}] :=
                  With[{tp = s1 - pt}, EuclideanDistance[tp, Projection[tp, s2 - s1]]]

segs = {{{20, 10}, {11, 27}}, {{11, 27}, {1, 27}}};
nf = Nearest[segs -> Automatic, DistanceFunction -> PointLineDistance];

PointLineDistance[{8, 15}, Extract[segs, nf[{8, 15}]]]
   159/Sqrt[370]
```

Trying to reproduce bel's isodistance plot on my box gives something rather different:

```
segs = Partition[Table[Through[{Cos, Sin}[2 Pi n/5]], {n, 5}] // N, 2, 1, 1];
nf = Nearest[segs -> Automatic, DistanceFunction -> PointLineDistance];

ContourPlot[PointLineDistance[{x, y}, Extract[segs, nf[{x, y}]]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
            AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors"]
```

[image: isodistance plot]

Finally, here's a three dimensional test:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> "MKL"]; (* for reproducibility *)
            segs = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50, 2, 3}]];

nf = Nearest[segs -> Automatic, DistanceFunction -> PointLineDistance];

Graphics3D[{Line[segs],
            {Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[4]], Line[Extract[segs, nf[{0, 0, 0}]]]},
            {Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]], Point[{0, 0, 0}]}}]
```

[image: nearest 3D segment test]

Comment: I think that `nf` in the first block finds the segment whose extended line is closest to a point. But the problem is about distance to a segment only, not to its extended line, isn't it?

Comment: How then do you define "distance to a segment"?

Comment: Something like `Min[EuclideanDistance[p1 + t (p2 - p1), p3]]` with `0 < t < 1`.

Answer (score 2):

```
p1 = {{8, 15}};
polyline = {{{20, 10}, {11, 27}}, {{11, 27}, {1, 27}}};
```

Discretizing the segments:

```
(* decrease dt for better result *)
data = With[{dt = .1},
  Flatten[polyline /. r : {{_, _}, {_, _}} :>
     Table[s[[1]] + t (s[[2]] - s[[1]]), {s, r}, {t, 0., 1, dt}], 1]];

p2 = Nearest[data, p][[1]]
(* {{15.5, 18.5}} *)

EuclideanDistance @@ Join[p1, p2]
(* 8.27647 *)

Graphics[{
  Thick, Line@polyline,
  PointSize[Large], Pink, Point[p1~Join~p2]}]
```

[image: line]

I think this should work in 3D too and with any number of joined or disjoint segments.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to this problem is to use the image processing functions and operate directly on the image of the lines. Here we import the two lines from the OPs question, and take the `DistanceTransform`. Finding the value of the distance transform at the orange point gives the distance (in pixels) of that point from that line.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Inf9t.png"]; 
point = Round[First@ImageValuePositions[img, RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0.5]]]; 
distImg = DistanceTransform[img];
distImg // ImageAdjust
ImageValue[distImg, point]
```

[image]

```
91.418
```

Of course one would need to know the relationship between the scaling of the drawing and the distance covered by one pixel in order to convert back to the original units. Chances are this method will be very fast, especially when there are many lines (because the computation time is independent of the number of lines). It also works for curves of any shape, so it is very general. On the other hand, the answer is only approximate, as it works on the rasterized pixel positions and not on the underlying real-valued positions.