# Translating a "Point-to-Triangle" distance script from MATLAB to Mathematica

Tags: syntax, computational-geometry, matlab

Update - Thanks everyone for your responses!  After fixing a problem with vector normalization, the code below now works.

---

I'm a new user, and I was attempting to port some *Mathematica* code from MATLAB for calculating the minimum distance between a point in 3-space and a triangle in 3-space.  This is partly a result of me wanting to have this functionality in *Mathematica*, and, I suppose, a good opportunity to practice learning the *Mathematica* syntax.

The original MATLAB code isn't mine (and can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22857-distance-between-a-point-and-a-triangle-in-3d/content/pointTriangleDistance.m)), but appears to work well in MATLAB.  Unfortunately, my translated version of the script in *Mathematica* returns nonsense despite my almost verbatim copy of the script.

I hope this question isn't inappropriate, but can anyone spot any naïve errors during the translation?  Note that I had to change `D` to `Dnp` to avoid symbol protection issues.

```
P = {0.5, -0.3, 0.5};

P1 = {0, -1, 0};
P2 = {1, 0, 0};
P3 = {0, 0, 0};

vertices = {P1, P2, P3};

B = P1;
E0 = P2 - B;
E1 = P3 - B;

Dnp = B - P;
a = Dot[E0, E0];
b = Dot[E0, E1];
c = Dot[E1, E1];
d = Dot[E0, Dnp];
e = Dot[E1, Dnp];
f = Dot[Dnp, Dnp];

det = a*c - b*b;
s = b*e - c*d;
t = b*d - a*e;


If[(s + t) <= det,
  If[s < 0,
    If[t < 0,
      If[(d < 0),
        t = 0;
        If[(-d >= a),
         s = 1;
         sqrDistance = a + 2*d + f;
         ,
         s = -d/a;
         sqrDistance = d*s + f;
         ];
        ,
        s = 0;
        If[(e >= 0),
         t = 0;
         sqrDistance = f;
         ,
         If[(-e >= c),
           t = 1;
           sqrDistance = c + 2*e + f;
           ,
           t = -e/c;
           sqrDistance = e*t + f;
           ];
         ];
        ];
      ,
      s = 0;
      If[e >= 0,
       t = 0;
       sqrDistance = f;
       ,
       If[-e >= c,
         t = 1;
         sqrDistance = c + 2*e + f;
         ,
         t = -e/c;
         sqrDistance = e*t + f;
         ];
       ];
      ];
    ,
    If[t < 0,
      t = 0;
      If[d >= 0,
       s = 0;
       sqrDistance = f;
       ,
       If[-d >= a, 
         s = 1;
         sqrDistance = a + 2*d + f;
         ,
         s = -d/a;
         sqrDistance = d*s + f;
         ];
       ];
      ,
      invDet = 1/det;
      s = s*invDet;
      t = t*invDet;
      sqrDistance = s*(a*s + b*t + 2*d) + t*(b*s + c*t + 2*e) + f;
      ];
    ];
  ,
  If[s < 0,
    tmp0 = b + d;
    tmp1 = c + e;
    If[tmp1 > tmp0,
     numer = tmp1 - tmp0;
     denom = a - 2*b + c;
     If[numer >= denom,
      s = 1;
      t = 0;
      sqrDistance = a + 2*d + f;
      ,
      s = numer/denom;
      t = 1 - s;
      sqrDistance = s*(a*s + b*t + 2*d) + t*(b*s + c*t + 2*e) + f;
      ];
     ,
     s = 0;
     If[tmp1 <= 0,
      t = 1;
      sqrDistance = c + 2*e + f;
      ,
      If[e >= 0,
        t = 0;
        sqrDistance = f;
        ,
        t = -e/c;
        sqrDistance = e*t + f;
        ];
      ];
     ];
    ,
    If[t < 0,
      tmp0 = b + e;
      tmp1 = a + d;
      If[(tmp1 > tmp0),
       numer = tmp1 - tmp0;
       denom = a - 2*b + c;
       If[(numer >= denom),
        t = 1;
        s = 0;
        sqrDistance = c + 2*e + f;
        ,
        t = numer/denom;
        s = 1 - t;
        sqrDistance = s*(a*s + b*t + 2*d) + t*(b*s + c*t + 2*e) + f;
        ];
       ,
       t = 0;
       If[(tmp1 <= 0),
        s = 1;
        sqrDistance = a + 2*d + f;
        ,
        If[(d >= 0),
          s = 0;
          sqrDistance = f;
          ,
          s = -d/a;
          sqrDistance = d*s + f;
          ];
        ];
       ];
      ];
    ,
    numer = c + e - b - d;
    If[numer <= 0,
     s = 0;
     t = 1;
     sqrDistance = c + 2*e + f;
     ,
     denom = a - 2*b + c;
     If[numer >= denom,
      s = 1;
      t = 0;
      sqrDistance = a + 2*d + f;
      ,
      s = numer/denom;
      t = 1 - s;
      sqrDistance = s*(a*s + b*t + 2*d) + t*(b*s + c*t + 2*e) + f;
      ];
     ];
    ];
  ];

If[(sqrDistance < 0), sqrDistance = 0;];

dist = Sqrt[(sqrDistance)]
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to use lower-case letters for your variable names: C, D, E, I, K, N, and O are all reserved.

Comment: @cormullion Thanks. :)  I was just trying to stay "as true" to the original script as possible to make identification of errors easier.  So far there haven't been other flags for reserved variable names.

Comment: It might interest you to know that there is an (undocumented) built-in function, ``Graphics`Mesh`PointPolygonDistance[]`` that you might be able to use...

Comment: @J.M. Doesn't that only work in 2D?  The above script should handle the case for a 3D point a triangle embedded in 3-space.

Comment: you may check this answer http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20105/efficiently-determining-if-3d-points-are-within-a-surface-composed-of-polygons/20386#20386

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20085/distance-between-point-and-line-segments) is easy to adapt...

Comment: @cormullion I will work on other approaches, however, I'm really curious why my attempts to adapt the above script, which again works fine in Matlab, seems to fail?

Comment: I hope this doesn't sound too unfriendly, but this isn't really a code review site; at least, not for long and bulky code. This looks like a rather tedious job and my bet would be a misplaced bracket or another typo error.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries That's completely fair.  I think I'll accept cormullion's adaptation of belisarius' (very nice) solution.

Comment: Thanks! - although it's definitely worth waiting a day or two for the real experts to contribute additional answers (I failed maths at school..). As to your original code, I would say (without knowing anything about MatLab) that it's not a good idea to carry out low-level literal translations, but try to find equivalents for the higher-level tasks (vectors, etc). And that nested If statement would look bad in any language... You could usefully read [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) too.

Comment: @Richard, you're right, it's a 2D-only solution. At least you have something you can use in 2D. :)

Comment: @cormullion I don't know about you, but I've never had much success translating procedural code: the abstract problem (if not fundamentally procedural in nature) is often so obscured by the nested loops and conditionals that I have difficulty understanding what is actually going on. There is a tendency in papers for the authors to present algorithms procedurally using buggy, ill-defined pseudocode, which one assumes basically paraphrases their actual program. What is really required in these cases is a flowchart, but these seem to be rather passé nowadays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry I can't make sense of your Matlab code - too many nested `If`s. I don't know whether I've adapted [belisarius' answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20092/61) correctly:

```
point = RandomInteger[100, {3}];
triangle = RandomInteger[100, {3, 3}] ;
lines = Subsets[triangle, {2}];
nline[{start_, end_}, pt_] := 
  Module[{param = ((pt - start).(end - start))/Norm[end - start]^2}, 
    N@{pt, start + Clip[param, {0, 1}] (end - start)}]
```

Then:

```
EuclideanDistance @@ nline[#, point] & /@ lines
```

> {67.0659, 78.7704, 67.0103}

```
Graphics3D[{
 Sphere[point], 
 Polygon[triangle], 
 Red,
 Line[nline[#, point] & /@ lines]}, 
 Axes -> True]
```

[image: picture]

If I've done it right, upvote [his answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20092/61)!, if not, I'll delete mine...

Comment: I'm looking to calculate the minimum distance to the face of the triangle, but still this is very interesting!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting this just to show that in *Mathematica*, it is entirely possible to start from the definitions:

```
pointTriangleDistance3D[pt_?VectorQ, tri_?MatrixQ] := Module[{p1 = First[tri], s, t}, 
  Sqrt[MinValue[{SquaredEuclideanDistance[pt, p1 + {s, t}.Map[# - p1 &, Rest[tri]]],
                0 <= s <= 1, 0 <= t <= 1, s + t <= 1}, {s, t}]]]
```

There certainly are more efficient approaches, of course.