# Faster way to compute the distance from a point to a surface in 3D

Tags: performance-tuning, computational-geometry

I am trying to compute the shortest distance between a point and a triangle in 3D

```
distance[point_, {p1_, p2_, p3_}] := Module[{p, s, t, sol},
  p = s*p1 + (1 - s)*(t*p2 + (1 - t)*p3);
  MinValue[{(point - p).(point - p),
   0 <= s <= 1, 0 <= t <= 1}, {s, t}]];
```

but it seems to be quite slow, is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: As I unfortunately do not know your intended application this may not work for your purposes, however I would suggest to redefine your triangle as a hyperplane and use LeastSquares[]. This is as a built in function much faster compared to the iteration you have designed here.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Well, you can use the undocumented `RegionDistance` which does exactly this as follows: (**This answer, as written, only works for V9 as noted by Oska, for V10 see update below**)

here is a triangle in 3D

```
region = Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}];

Graphics3D[region]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now suppose you want to find the shortest distance from the point `{1, 1, 1}` in `3D` to this triangle just do the following:

Load the [Region](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39184/any-ideas-on-how-to-use-the-region-context) context

```
Graphics`Region`RegionInit[];
```

Then

```
RegionDistance[region, {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As a bonus, you can get the exact point on the triangle that is closest to the given point as follows:

```
RegionNearest[region, {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Visualize it

```
Graphics3D[{region, Darker@Green, PointSize[0.03], Point[{1, 1, 1}], 
  Red, PointSize[0.03], Point[{1/3, 2/3, 2/3}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update for Version 10**

The above undocumented functions used in this answer now works out of the box in **V10** so no need to load the `Region` context as I did above. Otherwise everything works as is. Also, now you can use the new `Triangle` function in place of `Polygon` above.

Comment: For what reasons all of these `Graphics` functions are undocumented..?

Comment: @Öskå, I have no idea :). They seem to be very useful functions from what I can tell.

Comment: @RunnyKine I tested your code and gain 50 times faster speed, thanks so much for your help

Comment: @tintin. Glad I could help.

Comment: @RunnyKine - Where can I find other undocumented Graphics functions?

Comment: BTW it's only for versions >=9 (once again) [v8 here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ejYmd.png)

Comment: @eldo. Try this ``?Graphics`Mesh`*``

Comment: @Öskå. Sorry to hear that :)

Comment: You do have something for ``?Graphics`Region`*`` right? It's empty in _v8_. It would be great to specify that it only works for _v9_ :)

Comment: @Öskå, yes in V9 that brings up a bunch of functions. I've added the notice.

Comment: @Öskå Related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39184/193

Comment: @Öskå the true V8 potector. ;)

Comment: @Kuba And proud to be! I'm always sad to see that these `Graphics` hidden functions are not here :(

Comment: Maybe you need `RegionNearest`?Or my English mislead me again?